# IBM Mobile First Platform Test Workbench 7.0 is too slow on Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

I have created an application in IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 using Jquery Mobile for android devices. My has app has more than 10 pages and each page contains Jquery mobile widgets like list view, Grid view, tables etc.

When I installed the app on android device, it behaves fine.

When I tried to test the app using IBM MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench 7.0, while recording it takes so much time for performing all actions. For example, click menu icon to open panel, which is taking more than two minutes.

App was tested in following devices and emulator:

```
1. Arm emulator (4.4.2, API Level 19)
2. Micromax A116
3. Samsung Galaxy Grand 2
```

I have followed these links:

[Testing mobile first applications using test workbench](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/advanced-topics/testing-mobilefirst-platform-applications-mobile-test-workbench/)

[Recording tests from the Android mobile test client](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.mob.rtwm.ditaval.doc/topics/tmobrecand.html)

I have increased the heap size to see ,is there any change in performance. But still no luck.

```
1. Emulator - 256M
2. Eclipse - Min Heap:1024M Max Heap:2048M
```

Comment: Hi, on which device to you record please ?

Comment: Snapshot could be the origin of the problem. Huge resolution of the screen can lead to such behavior. Can you try on emulator by decresing the size of the screen please ?

Comment: @dom this is fine when we are working in the Emulator. If we are testing in the device this may fail. Can we disable the snapshot while we record? Is there a way that we can set a check point[ex - while loop] whether the page/content is loaded.

Comment: @dom is there a way to avoid taking screenshots while recording?

Comment: no, screenshots are always taken during playback & recording.

Comment: You can try to increase the memory in your emulator setting

Comment: @dom, as I told earlier this can be work around for an emulator. But how to achieve the performance in Real device. Increasing the Heap cannot be done in real device.

Comment: Any possible way to improve the Test script execution time in Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a device issue, where it is not powerful enough.
Try with a top end device, like a Nexus 5 or 6 or Galaxy s6.